# Is there any function to add a new attribute to all of the existing mongodb objects in a collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have an existing database with the following schema

```
let Employee = new Schema({
    first_name: { type: String },
    last_name: { type: String },
    title: { type: String },
    email: { type: String },
    gender: { type: String },
    location: { type: String },
    phone: { type: Number }
```

as I already have many records present in my DB, I want to add a new attribute `branch` to my database. Is there any function for the same regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends whether you want to add the same value to all records in your DB, or whether you need each Employee to have a different branch.

You can enforce that your Schema Model has a branch by simply including it into your Schema like so:

```
let Employee = new Schema({
  first_name: { type: String },
  last_name: { type: String },
  title: { type: String },
  email: { type: String },
  gender: { type: String },
  location: { type: String },
  phone: { type: Number },
  branch: { type: String, default: 'some_branch'}
});
```

Now, when you return any Employees, they should have a branch by default, and the next time you save them, it will hard-save them to the DB.

If you need to update all records to have a branch, you can do something like:

```
EmployeeModel.updateMany({}, { $set: { branch: 'some_branch'} } function(err, res) {
  // Success!
});
```

**EDIT**

- Using Model.updateMany() will pass in the `{ multi: true }` option automatically.
- Using the $set operator will ensure that the specific field you need changed or added will be updated.
- You could turn this into an aggregate pipeline to use $addFields, however $set is an expression alias I believe and should give you access to everything you need.

Hope this helps!